# How to detect if a specific string (email domain) is entered into an input to add/remove attribute/class from a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I know how to do the remove/add class/attribute from a submit button, but I need to be able to apply this to a button based off of entry into an input.

The scenario is this, user enters their email address, but if it's at a specific domain, ex: xxxx@troopers.gov I then want to be able to apply/remove the class, and attribute from the submit button, since this is a domain they are not supposed to enter for a registration.

I have done some similar validation in the past, and tried a few different methods in jQuery .val(), indexOf, etc. But still can't seem to get it working.

I tried something like

```
var badDomain = 'troopers.gov';
```

and then

```
if (!$('#input').val() === badDomain) {
doStuff();
}
```

but it didn't seem to get me anywhere.

I thought I may be able to do this without using a RegEx (I don't have much experience with that)

Would be nice to be able to account for case as well... and I don't mind if the solution is jQuery, or pure JS... for learning purposes, it would be great to see how I could do it both ways...

Comment: theres ways around this.

Answer (score 1):

So this does what you want, by turning anything typed into the field in lower case and then comparing against a given array of bad strings. Any time the input field blurs, it checks and turns the submit on or off.

Take a look in the code to see some bad addresses for sample use.

```js
var badDomains = [
  "troppers.com",
  "fooBarBaz.org",
  "myReallyUselessDomainName.com",
  "a.net"
]
$(function(){
  $("#email").on("blur", function(){
    var addressBad = false;
    var thisEmail = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    for (var i=0; i<badDomains.length; i++){
      if (thisEmail.includes(badDomains[i])){
        addressBad = true;
      }
    }
    if (addressBad) {
      console.log("bad address!")
      $(".disabledButton").attr('disabled', "disabled");
    } else {
      console.log("not a bad address!");
      $(".disabledButton").removeAttr("disabled");
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <label for="email">Email:</label>
  <input type="text" name="email" id="email" />
  <input class="disabledButton" type="submit" disabled />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

simple workaround :

```js
var email = document.getElementById('email');
var checkEmail = document.getElementById('checkEmail');

checkEmail.onclick = function() {
 if ((email.value).includes('@troopers.gov')) alert('This email address cannot be used!');
}
```

```html
<input id="email">
<button id="checkEmail">Check Email</button>
```

there are multiple ways around though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex for this purpose.

---

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="InputTest" />

<button id="TestBtn" type="button">
    Validate
</button>

<p>
    Valid
</p>
```

---

CSS:

```
.valid{
  background-color:green;
}

.invalid{
  background-color: red;
}
```

---

JS:

```
$("#TestBtn").on("click",function() {

var pattern = /\S+@troopers\.com/gi;

var str = $("#InputTest").val();

var arr = str.match(pattern);

alert(arr);  // just to see the value

if(arr !== null){
    $("p").addClass("invalid");
}
else{
    $("p").addClass("valid");
}

});
```

---

Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oa9rcmwg/1/).  Basically, if what the user typed in the textbox matches the expression.. then the background color turns red, but if it doesn't match, then the background color turns green.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Remember to make your pattern end /gi in order to be both global AND case-insensitive, as per the OP's request.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following Regex for the Email property of the related Model in order to accept mails having 'abc.com' suffix:

```
[RegularExpression("^[a-zA-Z0-9_@./#&+-]+(\\.[a-zA-Z0-9_@./#&+-]+)*@abc.com$", 
    ErrorMessage = "Please enter an email with 'abc.com' suffix")]
```